# Trigger a component function on svelte store method

Tags: javascript, methods, svelte, store, subscribe

I have a svelte store with a method called 'right'. When right is triggered I want the function handleNextImage in my component file to run. I am unsure how to do this properly, thanks!

```
import { writable, get } from 'svelte/store';


const createMyStore = () => {
    const store = writable({
        Rows: [],
    });

    const { subscribe } = store;

    return {
        subscribe,
        right: (cb: (msg) => void) =>
            update((x) => {
             ....
            return x;
            }),
    };
};


export const myStore = createMyStore();
```

COMPONENT.SVELTE

```
import { myStore } from '@screens/home/myStore';

myStore.right(() => {
        console.log('go right in store');
        handleNextImage()

    });

const handleNextImage = () => {
        does a thing...
    };
```

Comment: I realize now that maybe that how i want to use the store is not the correct way its intended i think, i will need to change some value in 'right' and then react to that value change in the component i think.

Comment: If the component calls `store.right()`, then it is as simple as calling `handleNextImage()` in the next line.  If right is some kind of event, then yes, put it in what seems to be the callback function that `right()` accepts.  If that is not an event, and in reality you want the function to be called on the change of the value then do `$: if ($myStore) handleNextImage()`.  Not the use of a seemingly unnecessary IF.  It is to make the Svelte compiler run the code on changes of `$myStore`.

Comment: I am not sure what is the intended use, but if you want to trigger the `cb` within the `right` scope, just do something as

`right: (cb: (msg) => void) => update((x) => {  cb('new x is '+x);  return x; })`